# Banner admod mess up listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview, admob

I am trying to generate a listview.

When the listview is generated everything is working fine: the height of every item is fine. But, as soon as the banner is loaded, the height of first item become strange.

For every item inside the listview I am going to render an image of make the Imageview invisible (view.INVISIBLE);

Can I avoid this?

[image]

This is the xml item of the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/round_box"
    >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/immagine_logo"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:paddingLeft="5dip"
         android:paddingRight="5dip"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:maxWidth="60dip"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
         android:src="@drawable/circle_logo"

          />

     <TextView

         android:id="@+id/Ingre_item_ingrediente"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text="nome di una ricetta miolto lunga che deve per forza andare a capa"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/immagine_logo"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Ingre_item_grammi"
         android:paddingTop="10dip"
         android:paddingBottom="10dip"
         android:textSize="18dip"
         android:textColor="#FF000000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         />


    <TextView 

        android:id="@+id/Ingre_item_grammi"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
         android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:text="400.75 gr."
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:paddingTop="10dip"
         android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:textSize="18dip"
         android:textColor="#FF000000"
    /> 

     <TextView 

        android:id="@+id/id_alimento"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the visibility as View.INVISIBLE, make it as View.GONE

Comment: That ALMOST work! The height is ok, but the Textview in the middle is too near on the other Textview! I am going to try something in the xml again! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the attributes `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` of your ListView are set to `fill_parent`